# Python/SQL Send confirmation email, reset database periodically

Tags: python, mysql

I am attempting to create an online estimate scheduler for my company. I am creating a database full of times for a one week period. There will be associated check boxes with these database entries and if a user selects a date and time I plan to drop the specified time from the database and then send an email to my account with their provided information as well as the time. I want the database to automatically reset each 7 days so that all times are available for that week. I am having a couple of issues....

I am using mySQL and python for the scripting. I can not figure out how to mail to myself, and I do not know how to periodically reset the database without my intervention. If you guys could shed any light on this it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: These are two independent issues ("resetting" a SQL Database in Python, and sending e-mails in Python), and there are not any details as to the specific questions of those two issues.

Answer (score 0):

E-mail could be taken care of using the [smtplib](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html) and [email](http://docs.python.org/library/email) modules.  These two example links may help: [Example1](http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html), [Example2](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html#smtp-example).

As far as "periodically" doing things, you'll find that [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) is an amazing utility.  It allows you to schedule things to happen on a recurring basis. In your case, you would develop a small script that would do the "reset" that you want and schedule it in cron to run weekly.  Some good example docs are found [here](http://www.markus-gattol.name/ws/time.html#cron).

If you're running on windows instead, look into the Windows scheduler to do the same thing.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the help pointing me in the right direction. I will get to work and post my results. Give me a while though, works busy!